# String segmentation fault with va_arg

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, variadic-functions

I am making a function similar to printf, it needs to take in a string and arguments like:

`form("Integer %d, String %s", 54, "STRING");`

and make a string `"Integer 54, String STRING"`.
I am using `stdarg.h` library because my function needs to have variable number of arguments depending on the string.

The problem is I am getting a `Segmentation fault`. I figured out that it only happens when I do `strlen` or `strcpy` with a string(char*) I passed to `va_arg`. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

char* form(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;char sign;int br=0,lasti,memo=0;char* help;
    int ints; float floats; double doubles; char chars; char* strings;
    va_start(ap,format);
    char* result=(char*)calloc(100,strlen(format));
    strcpy(result,format);
    for(int i=0; result[i] ;i++)
        if(result[i]=='%')
        {   
            switch (result[i+1])    
            {
                case 'd': {
                    ints=va_arg(ap,int);
                    int b,save=ints,dec=1,j;char *p=result+i;
                    for(b=0;save;b++) {save/=10;dec*=10;}
                    for(dec/=10,j=0; dec ; j++) { p[j]=((ints/dec)%10)+0x30; dec/=10; }
                    strcpy(result+i+b,format+i-memo+2);memo+=b-2;
                } break;

                case 'f': {
                    floats=va_arg(ap,double);

                } break;

                case 'l': {
                    doubles=va_arg(ap,double);

                } break;

                case 'c': {
                    chars=va_arg(ap,int);
                    result[i]=chars;
                } break;

                case 's': {
                    strings=va_arg(ap,char*);
                    strcpy(result+i+strlen(strings),format+i-memo+2);memo+=(strlen(strings)-2);
                } break;

                default: printf("Unknown type.\n"); break;
            }
            i=0;
        }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char a[100];
    scanf("%s",a);
    char*s=form("treci %s peti",a);
    printf("%s", s);

    printf("\n");
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The only way strlen or strcpy could cause a segfault is if a string isn't null terminated, but mine are. So what is wrong here and how do I fix it?

EDIT: Added code.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Or at least show us a larger part of the `form` function? We really need to see things like variable declarations and definitions and initializations.

Comment: And is there a reason you don't use e.g. [`vsnprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) to format the string? You can get it to tell you the exact length it needs, so you can allocate memory dynamically for the string if needed. If will also give you all of the standard formatting, including formats you don't handle, field widths etc.

Comment: I didn't learn vsnprintf in my course yet.

Comment: `i=0` at the end of `if(result[i]=='%')` is not correct.

Comment: That `strcpy` call looks like the possible suspect. Try instead e.g. `memcpy(result + i, strings, strlen(strings)); strcpy(result + i + strlen(strings), format + i + 2);`

Comment: Yes, `i=0` is incorrect. I forgot I put it there, was trying to solve something with integers. But why does it cause segfault, it would only mean it starts at the beginning of the string again..

Comment: Because of loop restart and `strings=va_arg(ap,char*);` will give you rubbish.

Comment: Note that `i` can't be a valid index for both `format` and `result` after you have converted a format. You need two different indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested for %s case only

```
char* form(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;char sign;int br=0,lasti,memo=0;char* help;
    int ints; float floats; double doubles; char chars; char* strings;
    va_start(ap,format);
    char* result=(char*)calloc(100,strlen(format));
//    strcpy(result,format);
    for(int i=0; format[i] ;i++)
    {
        if(format[i]=='%')
        {
            switch (format[i+1])
            {
                case 'd': {
                    ints=va_arg(ap,int);
                    int b,save=ints,dec=1,j;char *p=result+i;
                    for(b=0;save;b++) {save/=10;dec*=10;}
                    for(dec/=10,j=0; dec ; j++) { p[j]=((ints/dec)%10)+0x30; dec/=10; }
                    strcpy(result+i+b,format+i-memo+2);memo+=b-2;
                } break;

                case 'f': {
                    floats=va_arg(ap,double);

                } break;

                case 'l': {
                    doubles=va_arg(ap,double);

                } break;

                case 'c': {
                    chars=va_arg(ap,int);
                    result[i]=chars;
                } break;

                case 's': {
                    strings=va_arg(ap,char*);
                    strcpy(result+memo,strings);
                    memo+=strlen(strings);
                } break;

                default: printf("Unknown type.\n"); break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            result[memo++] = format[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Many problems:

1. `strcpy(result+i+strlen(strings),format+i-memo+2);` is coping format to result. What you need is to copy the string passed as variable argument to the result string. Futhermore `result+i+strlen(strings)` does not make any sense: why did you wrote that?
2. There was a `i=0` each time you find out a format specifier `%`: why? this was the root cause of **segmentation fault**. The loop restarts each time `%` is found, and a new variable argument is requested, but no other still to be retrieved.
3. you must have 2 different indexes to parse input format sting and to index the result string, due to the fact that output string will, probably, have a different length.

Comment: Because it isn't a complete code. With that line I wanted to make space for the string that I will put there.

Comment: Only `i=0` was the problem. Now I just `case 's': {strings=va_arg(ap,char*); strcpy(result+i+strlen(strings),format+i-memo+2);memo+=(strlen(strings)-2);memcpy(result+i,strings,strlen(strings));} break;` and it works.

Comment: `strcpy(result+i,strings)` should be `strcpy(result+memo,strings)` so that the code works for more than one format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`vsnprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) makes it very simple:

```
char *form(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);

    int result = vsnprintf(NUll, 0, format, va);

    // Error checking
    if (result < 0)
        return NULL;

    // Here result is the number of bytes we need to allocate (excluding terminator)
    char *string = malloc(result + 1);

    // Now do the actual formatting
    vsnprintf(string, result + 1, format, va);

    return string;
}
```

Important: Remember to `free` the string you return.